# Java How to parse specific info in log files by java

Tags: java, android, parsing

I have generated a battery stats log file. I want to parse specific information inside it. Here is the log

> Battery History (0% used, 200 used of 256KB, 5 strings using 248):
>                       0 (9) RESET:TIME: 2016-08-22-16-22-37
>                       0 (1) 081 status=charging health=good plug=usb temp=347 volt=4081 +running +wake_lock +wifi_multicast +wifi_radio +screen +plugged brightness=dim +wifi_running +wifi wifi_signal_strength=4 wifi_suppl=completed
>                       0 (2) 081 fg=u0a250:"com.sonymobile.lifelog"
>                       0 (2) 081 top=u0a119:"com.sonyericsson.home"
>                       0 (2) 081 user=0:"0"
>                       0 (2) 081 userfg=0:"0"
>                +2s544ms (3) 081 status=discharging plug=none temp=340 volt=8236 -plugged
>                +6s164ms (2) 081 -top=u0a119:"com.sonyericsson.home"
>                +6s165ms (2) 081 +top=u0a215:"com.skysoft.kkbox.android"
>   Estimated power use (mAh):
>       Capacity: 3430, Computed drain: 1.92, actual drain: 0
>       Screen: 1.08
>       Uid u0a215: 0.301 ( cpu=0.215 wifi=0.0860 )
>       Uid u0a48: 0.138 ( cpu=0.0419 wifi=0.0958 )

I want to parse info of uid = 'u0a2618' in this log file.
Information like this

> Estimated power use
>     Uid u0a215: 0.301 ( cpu=0.215 wifi=0.0860 )

I want to parse it and regenerates a log file which exactly shows the power use like this mock up.

> Uid u0a215: = 0.0352

I'm pretty new to java and still learning it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `Uid u0a2618: 0.0352 ( cpu=0.0350 wifi=0.000222 )`. That information is not in your log file. So how would you parse it out?

Comment: @greenapps it's surly inside the log because I just show part of my log file.

Comment: You should indeed show only a part of the log file. But the things you want to parse out should be visible to us.

Comment: @greenapps I've edit my question. Thanks for reminding

Comment: `want to parse info of uid = 'u0a2618' ` ??? u0a2618 is still not in your logfile so i have no idea what you want to parse out for it.